# Acer 3680 Ubuntu 14.04 No WIFI

Tags: wireless, acer

```
lynda@lynda-Aspire-3680:~$ lspci -vnn | grep 14e4 
0a:03.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)

lynda@lynda-Aspire-3680:~$ sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
[sudo] password for lynda: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

The process seems to be hanging after 'install completed':

Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.13.0-37-generic
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.13.0-37-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-37-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.

In another Terminal I get:

nmcli nm
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN
running         connected       enabled         enabled    enabled         disabled

Cannot afford to spend any more time on this. 14.04 has been a disappointment - have had more problems on recent installs than I ever had on 12.04. Will now downgrade.

Comment: Rather than b43-fwcutter, I recommend you install _firmware-b43-installer_.

Answer (score 1):

```
Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

This usually means you have another window open somewhere that is running updates or installing software. You can only run one dpkg process at a time. Ensure that other operations are finished and you do not have another package manager like synaptic running when you run an apt-get command